# Sync folder based on Amazon s3

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3

I have an Amazon s3 bucket, and wish to have the app data folder for my .net application sync itself to reflect changes in the bucket.

So, for instance if a user uploads a photo through my web application. When they launch the desktop application I want the app data folder to sync with the bucket state, so it would automatically download the uploaded photo etc.

Is there any api or sdk made for this? I've seen examples of an application updating a bucket to reflect changes to local storage but I wish to do it the other way around.

Comment: amazon have sdk for it http://aws.amazon.com/articles/3051?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1

Comment: I've seen the SDK, I was clarifying if there was a built in sync command, as I can't find any information on it.

Comment: i doubt it there is no sync command. but you can create one for your own. check this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/131678/Amazon-S3-Sync

Comment: Cheers for this, I actually wrote my own using the SDK yesterday. And it's working quite well.